# How can I combine two select queries in the following code?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can I combine last two select queries into one query?

```
DECLARE @AttributeLink table(qeaId int,nQeaId int)

insert into @AttributeLink values(100,200)
insert into @AttributeLink values(101,201)
insert into @AttributeLink values(102,202)

declare @prmVar varchar(200)

select @prmVar = COALESCE(@prmVar + ',', '') + cast(nQeaId as varchar) 
    from @AttributeLink  
    where qeaId in (100, 101)   

select @prmVar
```

Comment: Simple answer is no. The assignment in the select can't return recordset.

Comment: i tried to place similar select query into a insert query

Comment: exactly. previously qeaId is single value and i can directly join @AttributeLink table. now qeaId comes as coma separated.

Comment: Why do you want to combine them?  What are you trying to accomplish?  I think you should ask another question, elaborating on your comments, explaining what you want to accomplish with examples of data and results.

Comment: For eg. 100 200,201; 101 200, 201?

Comment: Possibly you can use recursive CTE

Answer (score 0):

Set the value of `@prmVar` when you declare it and then you can use select one.

```
DECLARE @AttributeLink table(qeaId int,nQeaId int)

insert into @AttributeLink values(100,200)
insert into @AttributeLink values(101,201)
insert into @AttributeLink values(102,202)

declare @prmVar varchar(200) = ( 
    
    
    stuff
        (
            (
                select ', ' + convert(nvarchar(max),nQeaId)
                from @AttributeLink al
                where al.qeaId in (
                    100
                    ,101
                )
                for xml path('')
            )
            ,1
            ,1
            ,''
        )

    ) 



select @prmVar
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you just did this?

```
select COALESCE(@prmVar + ',', '') + cast(nQeaId as varchar) 
from @AttributeLink  
where qeaId in (100, 101)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using

```
UNION / UNION ALL
```

between the tables

then you have at least one result. If the selected fields are the same then you can use this.

Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx